# In Xamarin.Android, should a ViewModel be re-instantiated every time a View is hit?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.android

I have a solution which is using mvvm and xamarin.android.  Every time I hit a view, its view model is re-instantiated.  Should this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal. Every time that the activity is instanciate, the ViewModel will be instanciate too.